# Confusion Matrix to Calculate Probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, accuracy, confusion-matrix

I was asked a relatively simple problem and was curious as to how to solve.

Say I had a bomb detector at the airport, and it is 99.99% correct. That being, when the detector goes off or does not go off, it is correct 99.99% of the time. And in the population, 1/10,000 people actually have a bomb.

**What is the probability that when it went off, the person actually had a bomb?**

EDIT** 
This is a Bayes Theorem question. We want to know the probability of a person having a bomb given the false positive/ true positive probability as given [here](https://betterexplained.com/articles/an-intuitive-and-short-explanation-of-bayes-theorem/)

Comment: The definition of "99.99% correct" is not clear.

Comment: You answered your question in the first paragraph: you told us that when the detector goes off, it is correct $99.99\%$ of the time.  If that didn't refer to the probability, what does it mean?

Comment: @whuber if you can take off hold I will answer the problem.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This is routine bookwork (as is commonly set for homework, for example). Please add the `self-study` tag, and read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). If you post an answer (as you suggest in comments that you will) that would take the place of showing an attempt.

Answer (score 2):

As you claim that 1 in 10000 has a bomb, we  can construct following confusion matrix (assuming our population has a size of 10000, WLOG):

```
           Bomb     NoBomb
Detected   TP          FN   
Not Det.   FP          TN
            1         9999
```

Your definition of "correctness" is called [Accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)

$ Accuracy =  \frac{TP + TN}{TP + TN + FP + FN}= \frac{9999}{10000} = 0.9999 $

So mathematically we have 2 variants: either (TP=1, TN=9998), or (TP=0, TN=9999)

Your want to get the value of Precision, that is

$ Precision = \frac{TP}{TP + FN} $

So in first case we have the Precision=1, that is the system always detects the bomber, and in the second case, Precision=0 that is system never detects a bomber. And you have no indication which is really your case.

The purpose of this exercise is not to find the value of Precision. It is to show, that in case of highly imbalanced class distribution, the value of Accuracy is not really indicative, and should not be used to measure system performance. In reality, for imbalanced classes, discriminators tend to detect always the major class. So your bomb detection system will never find a bomber, and still will have excellent Accuracy ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's indeed a relationship Confusion Matrix to Bayes:
Bayes’ theorem is crucial for interpreting the results from binary classification algorithms, I will show that Bayes’ theorem is simply the relationship between precision and recall:
Suppose we have A and B case as 0 and 1.
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

```
dtype: int64
[[ 39 32]   71 =A
 [ 22 222]] 244 =B
  254 315

             Predict
Actual 0  [[ 39  32]    71
       1   [ 22 222]]  244
             61 254    315
```

1 precision: 222/254 =0.874 P(A/B)

2 recall: 222/244 =0.909 = Bayes P(B/A)

So the recall (sensitivity) results in Bayes P(B/A)

The probability P(B/A) = 222/244 = 0.91 is called the recall. It simply gives the percentage of the 244 actual B that were correctly predicted by our classification algorithm. We see that Bayes’ theorem is simply a relationship between recall and precision:

[Predict * precision / Actual = recall] = Bayes

(P_B*P_AB)/P_A = 0.9098360655737705

(P(B)*P(A/B))/(P(A)) = 0.9098 = P(B/A)
(254/315 * 222/254) / (244/315) = 0.9098

predict * precision / actual = recall

prior * likelihood / evidence = posterior

precision / recall = actual / predict

```
      precision    recall  f1-score   support

   0       0.64      0.55      0.59        71
   1       0.87      0.91      0.89       244
```

accuracy                           0.83       315

You can explore that more with a forked jupyter notebook in python:
https://github.com/maxkleiner/Bayes_theorem/blob/master/Bayes_Theorem.ipynb

Comment: Max, from your interactions on [SO] you know how to format posts. What you might not be aware of is that you can also use MathJAX to mark up equations: see the link in the editing window for help.  Applying formatting and markup would make your post more readable.  Including (in English) some explanations of the steps you seem to be outlining would also help people understand what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve this through Bayes Theorem or by using a Confusion Matrix. Both will arrive at the same equation.

When you say the test is 99.99% correct we will assume P(Detected | Bomb) = P(Not Detected | No Bomb) = 99.99%. If you use the confusion matrix we will have the following:

- Sensitivity = P(Detected | Bomb) = TP / (TP + FN) = 99.99%
- Specificity = P(Not Detected | No Bomb) = TN / (TN + FP) = 99.99%

Here is the solution using both Bayes Theorem and Confusion Matrix

### Using Confusion Matrix

| Detector | Bomb | No Bomb | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Detected | True Positive (TP) | False Positive (FP) | Total Detected |
| Not Detected | False Negative (FN) | True Negative (TN) | Total Not Detected |
| Total | Total Bombs | Total No Bombs | Total People |

What we know:

- Total People = 10,000
- Total Bombs = TP + FN = 1/10,000 = 0.01%
- Total No Bombs = (TN + FP) = 9,999/10000 = 99.99%
- Total = TP + FP + FN + TN = 10,000/10,000 = 100%
- Sensitivity = TP / (TP + FN) = TP / Total Bombs = 99.99%
- Specificity = TN / (TN + FP) = TN / Total No Bombs = 99.99%

We will be able to populate all the values of the confusion matrix as follows:

- TP = Sensitivity x Total Bombs = 99.99% x 0.01% = 0.0099%
- TN = Specificity x Total No Bombs = 99.99% x 99.99% = 99.98%
- FP = (1 - Specificity) x Total No Bombs = 0.01% x 99.99% = 0.0099%
- FN = (1 - Sensitivity) x Total Bombs = 0.01% x 0.01% = 0.000001%

| Detector | Bomb | No Bomb | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Detected | 99.99% x 0.01% = 0.0099% | 0.01% x 99.99% = 0.0099% | ~0.02% |
| Not Detected | 0.01% x 0.01% = 0.000001% | 99.99% x 99.99% = 99.98% | 99.98% |
| Total | 0.01% | 99.99% | 100% |

The original question is what is the probability that when it went off, the person actually had a bomb?

This is TP / (TP + FP)

FP = TP

So TP / (2 x TP)

= 1/2 = 50%

### Using Bayes Theorem

We have the following formula:

P(Bomb | Detected) = (P(Detected | Bomb) x P(Bomb)) / P(Detected)

We know the following

- P(Detected | Bomb) = 99.99%
- P(Bomb) = 0.01%

P(Detected) = P(Detected | Bomb) x P(Bomb) + P(Detected | No Bomb) x P(No Bomb)

- P(Detected | Bomb) = 1 - P(Detected | Bomb) = 99.99% = 0.01%
- P(No Bomb) = 1 - P(Bomb) = 1 - 0.01% = 99.99%

P(Detected) = 99.99% x 0.01% + 0.01% x 99.99% = 2 x (99.99% x 0.01%)

We are solving for: P(Bomb | Detected) = (P(Detected | Bomb) x P(Bomb)) / P(Detected)

Substituting all the values:
P(Bomb | Detected) = (P(Detected | Bomb) x P(Bomb)) / P(Detected)

P(Bomb | Detected) = (99.99% x 0.01%) / 2 x (99.99% x 0.01%) = 1/2 = 50%

Hope this helps